# How do I format my input field using replace regex with javascript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to format my `<input id="phone_number" type="tel" name="phone_number" maxlength="14">` to have a value like this `(123) 456-7890`

My current jQuery code:

```
jQuery("#phone_number").on("keypress", function(event) {
    var phoneReg = /[0-9]/g;
    var phoneKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if(!phoneReg.test(phoneKey)){
        // dont display characters
        return false;
    } else {
        // display numbers only
        var phoneNumberVal = jQuery("#phone_number").val();
        var phoneNumberUsFormat = phoneNumberVal.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/,"($1) $2-$3");
        jQuery("#phone_number").val(phoneNumberUsFormat);
    }
});
```

The code above can format a phone number like this: `(123) 456-7890` only `after` typing all the numbers.

What I want to happen is start adding a `parentheses` and a `dash` when the user reaches the `3rd` and `6th` digit

What I currently tried is this:

```
jQuery("#phone_number").on("keypress", function(event) {
    var phoneReg = /[0-9]/g;
    var phoneKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    if(!phoneReg.test(phoneKey)){
        // dont display characters
        return false;
    } else {
        // display numbers only
        if(phoneNumberVal.length < 4) {
            newNumber  = phoneNumberVal.replace(/(\d{3})/,"($1) ");
            jQuery("#phone_number").val(newNumber);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem with the updated code above is not being able to detect the `6th` digit then automatically add a `-`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: tags updated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to follow that process:

- If the current input's value is not corresponding to the `(XXX) XXX-XXXX` format, checks the number of digits only.

  - If more or exactly 6 (= `XXXXXX...`), converts to `(XXX) XXX-` plus the rest if present.
  - **Else** if bewteen 3 and 6 (= `XXX...`), converts to `(XXX)` plus the rest if present (note the last space in the format I wrote).
  - Then updates the input's value.
- Else if the displayed format is right, just avoid the possibility to type more characters.

The code snippet below (with some bonuses):

```js
$('#telephone').on('keyup', function(e) {
  // If not removing a character...
  // (Without that check, you'll not be able to remove characters correctly.)
  if (e.key !== 'Backspace') {
    let value = $(this).val();
  
    // If the value is not corresponding to wanted format...
    if (!/\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}/.test(value)) {
      // Only keeps digits.
      value = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

      // If we have at least 6 digits, converts the value to "(XXX) XXX-...".
      if (value.length >= 6) {
        value = `(${value.substring(0, 3)}) ${value.substring(3, 6)}-${value.substring(6)}`;
      }
      // If we have at least 3 digits (but less than 6), converts the value to "(XXX) ...".
      else if (value.length >= 3) {
        value = `(${value.substring(0, 3)}) ${value.substring(3)}`;
      }

      // Updates the input's value.
      $(this).val(value);
    }
    // If the format is correct, just avoid to have too much characters.
    else {
      $(this).val(value.substring(0, 14));
    }
  }
});

// Doesn't display unwanted characters.
// (Did this on a different event. Try replacing "input" by "keyup" to see why.)
$('#telephone').on('input', function() {$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d() -]/g, ''));});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="telephone">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this after the 6th character?

```js
$("input[name='phone']").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d)+$/, "($1)$2-$3"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="phone" maxlength="14" />
```

Comment: Hi. The answer that I am looking for is to start adding a parenthesis on the `3rd` digit then add a `-` on the 6th digit

Comment: Hey @ConanCarroll, I think Kévin's solution answers your question appropriately.